# Configuring spring transactions in spring integration dsl

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm currently configuring spring integration using spring-integration-dsl as follow

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundServer())
            .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
            .transform(...)
            .route(...)
            .transform(Transformers.toJson())
            .channel(...)
            .get();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    ....
}
```

I don't know how I can configure the flow to use the transaction manager I've configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Spring Integration Java DSL supports all transaction features, which are available for the XML [components](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/transactions.html).

Please, provide more info from where you want to start a transaction. And keep in mind that TX support is restricted to the Thread boundaries. So, you can start TX from the `poller` or from the JMS(AMQP) Message Driven Channel Adapter.

Or use `TransactionInterceptor` as an advice on any endpoint within the flow. But in this case the TX is restricted just only for the `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage`.

**UPDATE**

To start the TX for some part of flow isn't so standard task and it can be achieved as a `unit of work` some transactional black box. For this purpose we have a component like `Gateway`. So, you specify some interface, mark it with `@MessagingGateway`, add `@IntegrationComponentScan` alongside with `@EnableConfiguration` and mark the method of that interface with `@Transactional`. The `requestChannel` of this gateway should send message to some separate flow with JDBC and Jackson conversion and wait for the result to continue in the main flow. The TX will be finished on the return from that gateway's method invocation.

And call that gateway as regular `service-activator` from the `.handle("myGateway", "getData")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The inboundServer() is a TCP Inbound Gateway, and I want to start the transaction right when it receive message.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Which gain are you going to get with that TX on the raw TCP? Even if we can add TX-Interceptor there using AOP, the rollback won't return received message to the socket. Please, share more info for your use-case.

Comment: I'm not going to gain the TX on incoming raw TCP. My use case is that the incoming data is a request which will query the database. It will return a large data using jdbcTemplate and be serialized using Jackson. The problem with this approach is that all data have to be loaded into memory before being serialized. If the data is too large, it can cause out of memory. To overcome this, I've extended jdbcTemplate which return `java.util.stream.Stream`. The problem is that the stream is only opened inside tx. Once tx is closed, stream is closed. So I need tx open during serialization.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, I think what you're saying is that create a gateway with a method annotated by @Transactional and that method returns the json string?

Comment: Right. And keep in mind that flow must be `direct` single-threaded and rely on the `reply-channel` header, which is populated by the gateway